# How to create a dynamic list view with data retrieved from a SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android

How can I create a dynamic list view with data retrieved from a SQLite database?

My SQLite column name is `_Id,first_name,last_name,phone_number`.
I have created a list view

```
...1.......2........................3.................4        
..id...first_name+last_name.....phone_number.......check_box   //this is column name
```

Comment: you should create custom listview

Comment: how i can create custom view tell me in coding please if you are aware of this point please tell me.are you getting my question whats the problem with me.

Comment: see this link : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: i have see this link but i cant understand how to create list view in android